# Calculate individual squared

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

My project is in the field of urban design, I have to do a regression analysis, which I did't have any idea what was that. However, I did that and here is the screenshot of my result

[image: screenshot]

As you can see here, the adjusted R-squared is 93%

how can I calculate the individual R-squared for every x parameters. I have searched but I haven't found any simple and straight forward way to do that. All my master is depend on it, please help me if you can.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify for us what you mean by "individual R-squared"?

Comment: @whuber, Maybe I used a wrong term, I want to calculate that each X value how many percent has effect on the Y value. For example, X1 has 50% effect, X2 has 30% and X3 has 20%. I thought it could be calculated by R-squared for each X value

Comment: What you ask for doesn't exist unless all the variables are orthogonal.

Comment: @whuber, thank you so much for your responses. How can I know that the variables are orthogonal? My variables(X) are different parameter in a region in the city, for example X1 is how many people has access to public transport, or X2 is how many people is jobless or X3 is how many people is older than 75 years. and the Y parameter is the number of car in this region. I want to know that how many precent those parameters has an affect on the number of cars.

Comment: You can test whether $X_1$ is orthogonal to $X_2,X_3$ (and a constant) by running a regression of $X_1$ against $X_2$ and $X_3.$  Orthogonality implies the estimated slopes will be zero.  Run a similar test for $X_2$ and $X_3.$  For observational data like yours it's virtually certain the variables will not be orthogonal.  Orthogonality holds for designed experiments and when linear relations are enforced *via* the definitions of the variables.